# Netbeans 7.2 Restful Client Script does not work

Tags: rest, netbeans-7

I have created a sample Restful service from DB and created a test html form using **NetBeans 7.2**.
Although I can get and create entities from DB over Restful Webservice, delete operation does not work.

When I have analized **test-rebeans.js** I have realized that delete method is not tested yet.
Have you ever tried to test restful webservice using tools created by NetBeans?

```
delete_ : function(url) {
    window.alert(url);
    return this.httpRequest('DELETE', url, 'application/xml', true);
},
```

Comment: I just noticed the same thing. I verified that the delete operation is not being called by the test-resbeans client web page.